# For preparing watershed delineation with QGIS Grass module I couldn't find r.watershed module

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

For preparing watershed delineation here some one has described some steps as follows

After step 2, I want to get flow accumulation file, but I can not find this kind of module in GRASS, so I pass it and directly try the ***r.watershed module*.**

**I couldn't reach r.watershed module, where can I get that**

There are several input options in this module, like this：

- enter image description here
- Sign up or log in

Comment: Please add a screenshot and point to the URL of that document to better understand...